# Delete function in DataGridView of custom webpart

Tags: web-part, gridview

I have used a `DataGridView` in a custom webpart to show a list and add an auto delete button in it, but delete function is not working.

Below is my code for the same:

```
 protected void GridViewD_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                string itemId;
                itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                GridViewD.DeleteRow(Convert.ToInt16(itemId));
                Bind_Data();
            });

        }
```

The `initializeControl()` is also giving error in it, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete item operation explicitly then it will work

```
        string itemId;
    protected void grdcrud_RowDeleting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
       {
            itemId = grdcrud.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                DeleteRow(itemId);
                Bind();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
              Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
         }
    }

     public void DeleteRow(string ItemId)
    {  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Details");
                SPListItem item = null;
                item = list.GetItemById(int.Parse(ItemId));
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                item.Delete();
                list.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Bind() 
    {
      try 
     {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            { using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Details");
                    SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems();
                    DataTable dt = coll.GetDataTable();
                    grdcrud.DataSource = dt;
                    grdcrud.DataBind();
                 }
             }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {   
              Label1.Text = ex.ToString(); 
      }   
    }
```

[CURD Operations on SharePoint List](http://www.dotnetcodesg.com/Article/UploadFile/2/216/CRUD%20%28Create%20Read%20Update%20Delete%29%20Operations%20on%20a%20SharePoint%20List%20programmatically.aspx)